# WPF out of memory error when loading large amount of data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, charts

I need to process large amount of data into a single `List<ChartData>` for my custom control.
About 3 Million points it works fine after reaching the List Count 80,00,000 It throws the Out of memory error. Is there any count limit for List? Yes means shall I use any other Collection rather then the List.

Is there a better technique to load large amounts of data into memory?
The proplem is in the following function.If ChartIndexedDataPoint.Count is goes to above 30,00,000

```
 protected override void CalculateSegments(ChartSeries series, ChartIndexedDataPoint[] points)
    {
        double[] yCoef={0};
        IChartDataPoint startPoint = null;
        IChartDataPoint endPoint = null;
        ChartPoint startControlPoint = null;
        ChartPoint endControlPoint = null;
        if (points.Length >= 2)
        {
            NaturalSpline(points, out yCoef);
            if (series.ShowEmptyPoints == false && series.Area.EnableLazyLoading == true)
            {
                allpoints = new List<IChartDataPoint>();
                if (series.ActualYAxis.IsAutoSetRange == true || series.ActualXAxis.IsAutoSetRange == true)
                {
                    series.Segments.Clear();
                    series.Adornments.Clear();

                    for (int i = 0, count = points.Length; i < count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        startPoint = points[i].DataPoint;
                        endPoint = points[i + 1].DataPoint;
                        GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[i], yCoef[i + 1], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                    }
                    series.Segments.Add(new ChartFastSplineSegment(allpoints, points, series)); 
                    return;
                }
                if (series.Segments.Count != 0)
                {
                    ChartFastSplineSegment segment = ((ChartFastSplineSegment)series.Segments[0]);

                    if (segment.Points != null && segment.Points.Count < points.Length)
                    {
                        segment.GetSegmet(points[points.Length - 1].DataPoint, series);
                    }
                    else if (segment.Points == null || segment.Points.Count > points.Length)
                    {                           
                        for (int i = 0, count = points.Length; i < count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            startPoint = points[i].DataPoint;
                            endPoint = points[i + 1].DataPoint;
                            GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[i], yCoef[i + 1], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                            allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                            allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                            allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                            allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                        }
                        segment.UpdateSegment(allpoints, series);
                        segment.refresh = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {                        
                    for (int i = 0, count = points.Length; i < count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        startPoint = points[i].DataPoint;
                        endPoint = points[i + 1].DataPoint;
                        GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[i], yCoef[i + 1], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                    }
                    series.Segments.Add(new ChartFastSplineSegment(allpoints, points, series)); 
                }
            }
            else if (series.Segments.Count == 0 || series.internaldata_modified || allpoints.Count > points.Length)
            {
                allpoints = new List<IChartDataPoint>();
                series.Segments.Clear();
                series.Adornments.Clear();
                ChartIndexedDataPoint[] pts = points;
                List<ChartIndexedDataPoint> tempPointArray = new List<ChartIndexedDataPoint>();                    
                for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length-1; i++)
                {
                    switch (pts[i].DataPoint.EmptyPoint)
                    {
                        case false:
                            {
                                startPoint = points[i].DataPoint;
                                endPoint = points[i + 1].DataPoint;
                                GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[i], yCoef[i + 1], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                                allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                                allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                                allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                                allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                                tempPointArray.Add(pts[i]);
                                break;
                            }
                        case true:
                            {
                                if (allpoints.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    if (i < points.Length)
                                    {
                                        startPoint = points[i].DataPoint;
                                        endPoint = points[i + 1].DataPoint;
                                        GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[i], yCoef[i + 1], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                                        allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                                        allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                                        allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                                        allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                                    }
                                    tempPointArray.Add(points[i]);

                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                if (tempPointArray.Count != 0 && allpoints.Count != 0)
                {
                    series.Segments.Add(new ChartFastSplineSegment(allpoints, tempPointArray.ToArray(), series));
                }
            }
            if (series.Segments.Count > 0)
            {
                List<ChartIndexedDataPoint> tempPointArray = new List<ChartIndexedDataPoint>();
                List<ChartIndexedDataPoint> pts = points.ToList();

                if (!series.Contains_emptypt)
                {
                    int cnt = (allpoints.Count+4)/4;
                    while ((allpoints.Count + 4) / 4 != points.Length && (allpoints.Count + 4) / 4 < points.Length)
                    {
                        startPoint = points[cnt-1].DataPoint;
                        endPoint = points[cnt].DataPoint;
                        GetBezierControlPoints(startPoint, endPoint, yCoef[cnt-1], yCoef[cnt], out startControlPoint, out endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
                        allpoints.Add(endPoint);
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
                (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).m_points = allpoints;
                if (series.ActualXAxis.IsAutoSetRange || series.Zoomactionenabled)
                {                        
                    double X_MAX = allpoints.Max(x => x.X);
                    double X_MIN = allpoints.Min(x => x.X);
                    (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange = new DoubleRange(X_MIN, X_MAX);//xRange + cdpt.X;
                    if (series.ActualXAxis.RangeCalculationMode == RangeCalculationMode.AdjustAcrossChartTypes)
                    {
                        (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange += (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange.Start - 0.5;
                        (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange += (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange.End + 0.5;
                    }
                    (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).SetRange(series);

                }
                if (series.ActualYAxis.IsAutoSetRange || series.Zoomactionenabled)
                {                        
                    double Y_MAX = allpoints.Max(y => y.Y);
                    double Y_MIN = allpoints.Min(y => y.Y);

                    (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).yRange = new DoubleRange(Y_MIN, Y_MAX);//yRange + cdpt.Y;

                    if (series.ActualXAxis.RangeCalculationMode == RangeCalculationMode.AdjustAcrossChartTypes)
                    {
                        (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange += (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange.Start - 0.5;
                        (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange += (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).xRange.End + 0.5;
                    }

                    (series.Segments[0] as ChartFastSplineSegment).SetRange(series);
                    if (series.Zoomactionenabled)
                    {
                        series.Zoomactionenabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }     
    }
```

Comment: How do you assign the items to the list exactly ?

Comment: Do you not think maybe the problem is you are storing too much information in memory? rather than it being an issue with how many records a list can hold. Find a better way than storing so much in memory - use a database for example. If you need it for display purposes then consider some sort of "paged" list

Comment: Well I just tried adding 3,000,000 strings to a List<string> and that worked fine so it's not a limit on list on my Windows7 x64 machine.

Comment: Could you show us the CharData class?

Comment: More information is required.  Its possible to tell a x64 process to store HUGE amounts of data, the option has to be enabled, I have to downvote this question for lack of technical details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can your application make use of data virtualization? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Answer (score 2):

Even without memory issues, there's no meaningful way to present all of that information at once without summarizing it in some way. You have more data points than there are pixels in a 1920x1080 screen. You need to think of ways to reduce the number of points that make sense for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this issue.

```
allpoints.Add(startPoint);
allpoints.Add(startControlPoint);
allpoints.Add(endControlPoint);
allpoints.Add(endPoint);
```

allpoints into 4 lists

```
startPoints<IChartDataPoint>
endControlPointS<IChartDataPoint>
endControlPointS<IChartDataPoint>
endPointS<IChartDataPoint>
```